# Setting boolean flags in JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going nowhere with apparently a simple task of trying to set a boolean flag in Js / JQuery. I'm expecting that after btn1 click the flags should change (globally). But I likely misunderstand some inner works of JS and after clicking btn2 the status of flags stays exactly as initially declared - how can I go about this?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $btn1 = $("#btn1");
  var $btn2 = $("#btn2");
  var active1 = true;
  var active2 = false;

  $btn1.click(function(){
    $active1 = false;
    $active2 = true;
    alert("after btn1 click: --> " + " active1: " + active1 + ", active2: " + active2);
  });

  $btn2.click(function(){
   // If clicked first on btn1 I'm expecting active1=false; active2=true; ??
        alert("after btn2 click: " + " active1: " + active1 + ", active2: " + active2);
  });
});
```

---

```
   <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
   <button id="btn2">Button2</button>
```

[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Turo/wtksmam0/)

Comment: change  active1 = false; instead of  $active1 = false;

Comment: This isn't PHP - `active1` is one variable `$active1` is another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $ from in declaration. Note `active1` not `$active1` same for active2.

```
$btn1.click(function(){
    active1 = false;
    active2 = true;
    alert("after btn1 click: --> " + " active1: " + active1 + ", active2: " + active2);
  });
```

Comment: sure, I tried to wrap my head around a more complex case and I made a stupid mistake here. Good that it works though as expected, thank you.